# Laravel Cashier - updateCard() - guidance

Tags: laravel, laravel-cashier, stripe.js

I am using Laravel Cashier with Stripe checkout (to avoid need for compliance). I cannot fathom how to allow customer to change their card details. I know the cashier syntax is

```
$customer->updateCard($stripeToken)
```

but how do we get there? Anyone able to offer me the steps please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a good starting point to understand what Stripe expects tp update a customers card. Even though this is targeted towards vanilla PHP, it gives you a fair bit of detail as to what is required and what goes on behind the scenes. https://stripe.com/docs/recipes/updating-customer-cards

This explains further the inner working of `updateCard` https://github.com/laravel/cashier/blob/7.0/src/Billable.php#389

In your case, you need a view with a form for new card details. The view should implement Stripe's JS Checkout library which in turn generates the stripe token. In your controller you can pass that token to `updateCard` method on an instance of your user/customer model.

Answer (score 0):

Cashier expects a [token to be created](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/reference#stripe-create-token) client side using [stripe.js/elements](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js) or [checkout](https://stripe.com/checkout). You then submit this token to your server route where you call:

```
// grab the token from the request like this
// $stripeToken = request()->input('stripe_token');

$customer->updateCard($stripeToken);
```

The [Stripe API](https://stripe.com/docs/api/php#update_card) is itself really well put together and easy to use, so you can use it directly, as well:

```
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey("stripe_secret_test_key");

$customer = \Stripe\Customer::retrieve("cus_CFdeffeSfeefe");
$card = $customer->sources->retrieve("card_1sdafjkfsdD32f");
$card->name = "Joseph Jones";
$card->save();
```